# How to add retry event for server sent events?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, server-sent-events

This is my simple server sent event code.

```
public void Message()  
{  
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";  
  
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;  
    while (startDate.AddMinutes(1) > DateTime.Now)  
    {  
        Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", DateTime.Now.ToString()));  
        Response.Flush();  
  
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  
    }  
      
    Response.Close();  
}
```

How to add retry event for this to reconnect with client every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling and found the answer. Will post it here.
You can add below line after the first `Response.Write` in the question. In the follwing code line, I set to retry time for 1 second.

```
Response.Write("retry: 1000\n");
```